# Strange errors with jsdom - node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am trying to run simple code from examples:

```
require.paths.unshift('/etc/npm'); // path to modules
var httpAgent = require('http-agent'),
    jsdom = require('jsdom'),
    sys = require('sys');

var agent = httpAgent.create('www.twitter.com', ['', 'about']);

agent.addListener('next', function (e, agent) {
  var body = agent.body;
  var window = jsdom.jsdom(body, {},{}).createWindow();
  jsdom.jQueryify(window, 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js', function (window, jquery) {
    agent.next();
  });
});

agent.addListener('stop', function (agent) {
  sys.puts('the agent has stopped');
});

agent.start();
```

But it returns a lot of errors on this line:

```
var window = jsdom.jsdom(body, {},{}).createWindow();
```

Erros:

```
kir@nas:~/node$ node test.js

/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/jsdom/0.1.21/package/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:197
  if (!dom.HTMLDocument.write) {
                       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at Object.browserAugmentation (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/jsdom/0.1.21/package/lib/jsdom/browser/index.js:197:24)
    at Object.jsdom (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/jsdom/0.1.21/package/lib/jsdom.js:15:25)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/kir/node/test.js:12:22)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events:27:15)
    at Object.emit (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/http-agent/0.1.0/package/lib/http-agent.js:180:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node/.npm/http-agent/0.1.0/package/lib/http-agent.js:145:14
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node/.npm/request/0.10.0/package/lib/main.js:89:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events:41:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http:107:23)
    at Client.onData [as ondata] (http:848:27)
```

I have Ubuntu 10.10 with stable node.js 0.2.5. WTF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal for jsom, it's work in progress, the DOM API is gigantic and re-implementing all the Browser quirks takes a lot of time.

But first of all your call `jsdom.jsdom(body, {},{}).createWindow();` is wrong, second parameter should be a **fully configure DOM object**, if you don't provide one just pass `null` to make it fall back to a default one.

But after that it's turtles all the way down.

Twitter for example does this `window.top.location`, turns out that jsdom does not define `window.top` and BOOM!

Fixing that... yeah, turtles. The errors don't stop, if you're interested in fixing it all the way down, open `<npm folder>/jsdom/0.1.21/package/lib/jsdom/level2/languages/javascript.js` there you can log the code and do fixes to the `window` object till it works.

Comment: Oh, shit. I apologized, that jsdom works correctly and development was finished. It would be better to use PHP for parsing webpages.

Answer (score 3):

as a clarification here, your real problem was here: jsdom(html, **{}**, {}). the second argument of jsdom() is a level (level1/core, level2/core, level2/html, etc).  By passing an empty object you are essentially telling the jsdom method to operate without a corresponding W3c level.